# How much we should trust our brain

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience

Our brain is trained from culture and environment that we're raised in. So we don't control what we're learning until we get to teenage. But by that time our behaviour is already been shaped. This shapes our intuition part.

Also we can't be rational because we know so very less, how can a person take rational decision in constraint partially observable space. This shapes our analytical part.

So my question is how much we should trust our brain ? Neither intuitive nor analytical part is controlled by us !

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I'm not sure that I understand the question - ie, what this has to do with "trust"...  Are you maybe asking about how objectively we can think, or about the sense of will, or is "trust" referring to some sort of deception conducted by the brain?

Comment: I mean how much we should trust ourselves on any decision. We take decisions based on analysis or intuition, both of them prejudiced as I explained in the question. I used the word brain because all our decisions comes from over there only.

Comment: Although I agree there can be biases in intuitive reasoning I am not convinced that analytical thinking cannot be controlled.  Have you got any scientific references to back that idea?

Comment: @ChrisRogers no it's just an idea that popped up in my mind. I wanted some experts in this field to either tell me where I'm wrong/right or provide some references to drive my idea in certain direction.

Comment: In that case there may be supposition without foundation in materials read. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Can you please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly not trusting the brain in itself does more harm than good, as it gives way to paranoia and anxiety, and serves to be a very unhealthy mental disaster.

Secondly, there is much more to decision making in the brain than just intuition and the analytical part of function, as factors such as personality, perception stemming from the frontal , and gathered experiences and learned memory from the hippocampus work together as well and much more as the brain works in an integrated manner interlinking both conscious and subconscious aspects of the brain. But what the brain does best is learn from experiences, and it keeps doing so and the best way to maintaining a healthy life is to have a healthy brain, and a healthy brain demands trust and constant learning.

Thirdly recent evidences based on research suggest that the prefrontal cortex continues to get developed and shaped even until a person hits his 30’s while the other parts of brain continue to grow and develop which is where neuroplasticity also finds its role through out our life(Hötting & Röder, 2013).

If you guys want to further understand my comprehension,refer to this article, hope it was helpful:). **Reference : 
Hötting, K., & Röder, B. (2013). Beneficial effects of physical exercise on neuroplasticity and cognition. Neuroscience & Biobehavioral Reviews, 37(9), 2243-2257. doi: 10.1016/j.neubiorev.2013.04.005 
Mullally, S., & Maguire, E. (2013). Memory, Imagination, and Predicting the Future. The Neuroscientist, 20(3), 220-234. doi: 10.1177/1073858413495091**